# How to display serializers validation error message in vue template?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

Here I am using vue.js for the client side rendering and django-REST framework for the server side. I am customizing the `PasswordResetSerializer` class in order to check whether the entered email is registered in our database or not. If the email is not in our db then it does not send the success message, which is what I expect. But the validation error message is not shown. But I have configured the error message in the `PasswordResetSerializer` class, if there is not user with that email address.

Note: It displays the success message `Password reset email has been sent` if the email address is in our database.
Also the validation error message is displaying exactly in my backend but it is not displaying in my vue template form.

It is giving me this when i check with my vue template

```
Bad Request: /api/v1/admin/password/reset/
[15/Aug/2019 17:19:02] "POST /api/v1/admin/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 400 69
```

But when i enter this `/api/v1/admin/password/reset/` url through my django-rest backend then it throws the validation error message exactly like i configured in my code.But i needed to display this in my vue template also

How can I display the `serializers.ValidationError` message in my forgot password form ?

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.conf import settings


class PasswordResetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password_reset_form_class = PasswordResetForm

    def validate_email(self, value):
        self.reset_form = self.password_reset_form_class(data=self.initial_data)
        if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Error')

        if not User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Sorry.No user found with that email address.')

        return value

    def save(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        opts = {

            'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
            'request': request,
        }
        self.reset_form.save(**opts)
```

forgotpassword.vue

```
 <template>
    <div class="password-change-card">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="edit-card">
            <img class="edit-icon" src="@/assets/icons/edit.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <form @submit.prevent="sendPasswordResetEmail(email)">
            <div class="input-container">
                <img class="icon-password" src="@/assets/icons/user.png" alt="">
                <input class="username" type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div  class="error-message" v-if="error != null">
                {{ error.non_field_errors[0] }}
            </div>
            <div  class="error-message" v-if="success != null">
                {{ success.detail }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn forget-btn">Send Email
                <half-circle-spinner v-if="loading" class="spinner"
                    :animation-duration="1000"
                    :size="30"
                    color="#ffff"
                />
            </button>
        </form>
        <div>
            <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';
import { HalfCircleSpinner } from 'epic-spinners'
export default {
    components:{
        HalfCircleSpinner,
    },
    data() {
        return { 
            email: '',
            error: null,
            success: null,
            loading:false,
        }
    },
    computed: mapState('password', [
        'emailCompleted',
        'emailError',
        'emailLoading',
    ]),
    beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
        this.clearEmailStatus();
        next();
    },
    methods:{
        sendPasswordResetEmail(email){
            this.loading = true
            this.error = null
            this.success = null
            this.$store.dispatch('password/sendPasswordResetEmail', { email })
                .then(success => {
                    this.loading = false
                    this.success = success
                }
                )
                .catch(error=> {
                    this.loading = false
                    this.error = error
                }
                )
        },

        clearEmailStatus(){
            this.$store.dispatch('password/clearEmailStatus')
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

views.py

```
class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    Calls Django Auth PasswordResetForm save method.
    Accepts the following POST parameters: email
    Returns the success/fail message.
    """
    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a serializer with request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        serializer.save()
        # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
        return Response(
            {"detail": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

Comment: Where is your view?

Comment: i am using the default django rest auth for this  `url(r'^api/v1/admin/', include('rest_auth.urls')),`

Comment: That didn't answer the question. What is calling this serializer? What is returning the results?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are validating email in `validate_email` but I don't see it getting called anywhere.

`serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` will not call your `validate_email`. It will only check whether the request schema matches to that defined in `PasswordResetSerializer` i.e presence of `email` and it being a valid email field. Note that it doesn't check if the passed email exists in your DB `email = serializers.EmailField()`.

What you can do is

1:rename `validate_email` to `validate`. Calling this will be ensured by `.is_valid()`.

OR

2: Write your own (reusable) custom validator as `ExistingEmailValidator` and use it in serializer as `email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[ExistingEmailValidator])`

```
@deconstructible
class ExistingEmailValidator(EmailValidator):
    message = 'Sorry. No user found with that email address.'

    def __init__(self, message=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message

    def __call__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if not User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Sorry.No user found with that email address.')
```

Prefer 1st method if you're not using it anywhere else. Prefer 2nd one if you want to reuse this validator elsewhere.

Comment: the problem is  this validation error is not displaying in the vue template but it displays the message exactly in my backend.

Comment: Oh, in that case, can you `console.log` the error part in JS.
`.catch(error=> {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.error = error;
console.log(error);
                }`

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: No `Sorry.No user found with that email address.` message? Can you inspect the request in  browser's Network tab. if you are getting this message, all you need to do is displaying it in the form.

Comment: i inspect and went to the network tab and did ctrl+R after that i get the name websocket status 101.I don't what is it ?

Comment: Nothing on the lines of `/api/v1/admin/password/reset/`?

Comment: xhr.js?b50d:160 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/admin/password/reset/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: What is the response body?